# $paginator->numbers(); not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i am trying to use the pagination concept in Cakephp for my application ..

var $paginate = array(
                            'limit' => 5,
                            'order' => array(
                            'Report.report_id' => 'desc'
                            )
     );

ANd in the cakephp action

```
        $conditions=array('Report.user_id'=>$userId);
        $this->paginate['Report']['conditions']=$conditions;
        $this->paginate['Report']['group']='Report.report_id';
        $this->paginate['Report']['limit']=5;
        $allreports=$this->paginate('Report');
```

Now this gives me the actual 5 entries of the Query with the group by condition but i m not getting the page numbers now in the View..

in the View

i have used like

```
         <?php  echo $paginator->numbers(); ?>
```

but it doesnt displays anything ?? why so.. guide me...

Answer (score 3):

Although `Model::find()` supports the `group` parameter, support for it has not been implemented for pagination. If you pass a `group` into `$paginate`, although it will return the correct results, it will return an inconsistent record `COUNT` (used to determine the number of pages). There is a [ticket to add support for this](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/5123) but it won't be implemented until CakePHP 2.x. In the meantime, you will have to override `paginateCount()` in your model as outlined in the examples under [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/249/Custom-Query-Pagination) in the manual.